# Datetime e Pytz

Tags: python

Estou com um projeto no gitlab que foi pra deploy onde trabalho. Ele apresentou os seguintes erros:

```
UserWarning: Can not find any timezone configuration, defaulting to UTC.
TypeError: Only timezones from the pytz library are supported.
```

Todas as rotinas do projeto estão setadas da seguinte forma:

```
import __int__
import pandas as pd
from password import password
from ******* import DWConnection
import os
import datetime
from utils.replace_all import *
utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
now = (utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
def get_local_datetime():
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()
    return dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

Se eu entendi bem não tenho timezone sendo definido, ele pega o UTC porém não suporta.

Pergunta: Sou iniciante no python e gostaria de saber como faço pra alterar o descrito acima para utilizar a lib pytz.

Já agradeço antecipadamente.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Só com o código da pergunta, não ocorre o erro indicado. Talvez o problema esteja em outro lugar que não foi mostrado. De qualquer forma, o pytz pode ser instalado via pip ([veja aqui](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/)), mas se estiver usando Python >= 3.9, agora existe o [módulo zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html)

Answer (score -1):

Primeiramente, instale a biblioteca [`pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) no seu [`virtualenv`](https://pythonacademy.com.br/blog/python-e-virtualenv-como-programar-em-ambientes-virtuais). Em seguida, eis uma sugestão de como aplicar o `utc`:

```
import os
import pytz
import datetime


class TimeMachine:

  def __init__(self, format):
      # indicando o UTC fornecido pelo pytz
      self.utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
      self.now = self.utc_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

  def get_local_datetime(self):
      return self.now

tm = TimeMachine()
tm.get_local_datetime()
```

Para entender um pouco melhor qual a diferença entre o puro datetime.datetime.now utilizado com e sem o parametro de UTC, consulte [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433171/when-to-use-datetime-utcnow-or-datetime-nowtz-pytz-utc-replacetzinfo-none)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).